# Good resources on Facebook programming

Tags: facebook

I'm a Facebook programmer newbie.
Could anybody recommend good resources for starters?
I believe it has something to do with PHP.

Comment: If you want to start there is a "for dummies" book which will get you started

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you can write Facebook applications in most languages.  The [Facebook Developer Site](https://developers.facebook.com/) is a good place to start.

Comment: Yes, http://code.google.com/p/delphibook/

Answer (score 8):

I have written the following to help people get a jump start on Facebook Application Development.


[How to Use the Facebook Developer Toolkit 2.0](http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-use-the-facebook-developer-toolkit-20)
[How to Style an Application Like Facebook](http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-style-an-application-like-facebook)
[How to Integrate Facebook Connect](http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-integrate-with-facebook-connect/)

Comment: 3rd link should be http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-integrate-with-facebook-connect/

Answer (score 3):

There is a book entitled: "[Facebook Cookbook: Building Applications to Grow Your Facebook Empire](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059651817X)" I liked it

Answer (score 3):

If you have already added the [facebook developer](http://developers.facebook.com/) application there is a link to the [developer forums](http://forum.developers.facebook.com/).  And of course it appears [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is a great place for such questions as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here You can find some interesting material: [50 Resources for Facebook Application Developers](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/50-resources-for-facebook-application-developers/).

Answer (score 1):

you could try [FBML Essentials](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596519184) by  Jesse Stay and [Facebook Application Development (Programmer to Programmer)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470246669).