# Where should I start with a facebook application?

Tags: facebook

I am thinking about developing a fairly simple facebook application which i have modelled the database in access.
I have web space and mySQL databases available, but I was wondering if anyone could point me towards any guides for facebook development? I had a search a while back, but they all seemed rather out of date. Anyone know where I should start with this?
I don't want to really share exactly what my idea is, but its a rating system for a particular set of products.
I haven't done much PHP before, only edited my wordpress template, and I do know enough SQL I hope.

Comment: Do u need to integrate ur application with facebook platform?

Comment: I havent yet designed the application, only come up with the idea and the database for it. I believe I need to lean PHP, I was just looking for any half decent guides. I trust stack overflow people better than google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following links to create and configure ur application on facebook:
http://www.facebook.com/developers/

and the following links will help u to integrate with facebook platform i have an application on facebook developer platform and the following links helped me to integrate and use facebook API:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/C

http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-use-the-facebook-developer-toolkit-20/

Comment: sadly i dont know C#, however I do know java.
I may design an admin like interface for myself which interacts with my application.

Answer (score 1):

You might find some good resources to start with here : [Good resources on Facebook programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454051/good-resources-on-facebook-programming)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you buy...

http://pragprog.com/titles/mmfacer/developing-facebook-platform-applications-with-rails

No need to go through a bunch of small tutorials when you can find out just about all you can do through this book.  It seems to be lacking on building a facebook app with an iframe though.