# Facebook Application Development Resources

Tags: php, facebook

I am starting to develop an app in PHP which will make heavy use of various facebook API's and thought it would be useful to get some tips on places to go to start looking into best practices, potential pit falls and other tips and tricks.

Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good resources on Facebook programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454051/good-resources-on-facebook-programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to start would be http://developers.facebook.com/ - but there are plently of websties that cover social network integreation / development.

nettuts.com , smashingmagazine.com are just a couple of places to look.

Answer (score 2):

These are some links i used
[-facebook-application-gotchas](http://20bits.com/articles/5-facebook-application-gotchas/)

[facebook-app](http://www.focus.com/briefs/software-development/developing-hit-facebook-app/)

[Step by Step Guide to Creating a First Facebook App](http://aleatory.clientsideweb.net/2009/07/05/step-by-step-guide-to-creating-a-first-facebook-app/)

[Facebook-Programming-API-Friends](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Facebook-Programming-API-Friends-P851.html)

[build-your-first-facebook-app](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/build-your-first-facebook-app/)

[ssential-graph-api-of-facebook](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/essential-graph-api-of-facebook/)

[php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/)